# How to detect first visit of a user?

Tags: functions, users

I want to build an alert for users who visit my WordPress blog. Is there a conditional function like `is_home()` to detect if someone visits the blog the **first time**? I want to send the alert to every new user no matter on which site he entered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's nothing in the core like that.

You can set a cookie and do it simply enough (warning: untested code follows).

```
<?php
function is_first_time()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['_wp_first_time']) || is_user_logged_in()) {
        return false;
    }

    $domain = COOKIE_DOMAIN ? COOKIE_DOMAIN : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    // expires in 30 days.
    setcookie('_wp_first_time', '1', time() + (WEEK_IN_SECONDS * 4), '/', $domain);

    return true;
}

if (is_first_time()) {
     // it's the user's first time, do stuff!
}
```

Just make sure you have output buffering turned on or use that before anything gets sent to the screen to make sure the cookie gets set.

Answer (score 1):

Modified a bit from chrisguitarguy. Place in your functions.php file, and use the conditional in theme templates, etc. via the hook

```
function is_first_time() {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['_wp_first_time']) || is_user_logged_in()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // expires in 30 days.
        setcookie('_wp_first_time', 1, time() + (WEEK_IN_SECONDS * 4), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);

        return true;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'is_first_time');
```